# Error when creating an IronPython project in VisualStudio; "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I have a solution which will have a GUI built in on C# and I want to create a IronPython project in the solution which will be called from the C# code but I can't even create it.

I'm using the python tools from CodePlex and IronPython 2.7

Edit: This is I found in the ActivityLog.xml

> `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Failed to load language 'IronPython 2.7.2.1': Method not found: '!!1[] Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ArrayUtils.ConvertAll(!!0[], System.Func2<!!0,!!1>)'. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!1[] Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ArrayUtils.ConvertAll(!!0[], System.Func2)'. at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext..ctor(ScriptDomainManager manager, IDictionary2 options) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LanguageConfiguration.LoadLanguageContext(ScriptDomainManager domainManager, Boolean& alreadyLoaded) at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DlrConfiguration.LoadLanguageContext(ScriptDomainManager manager, LanguageConfiguration config) at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DlrConfiguration.TryLoadLanguage(ScriptDomainManager manager, AssemblyQualifiedTypeName providerName, LanguageContext& language) at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.ScriptDomainManager.GetLanguageByTypeName(String providerAssemblyQualifiedTypeName) at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptRuntime.GetEngineByTypeName(String assemblyQualifiedTypeName) at IronPython.Hosting.Python.GetEngine(ScriptRuntime runtime) at Microsoft.IronPythonTools.Interpreter.RemoteInterpreter..ctor() at Microsoft.IronPythonTools.Interpreter.RemoteInterpreterProxy..ctor() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName) at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName) at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName) at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName) at Microsoft.IronPythonTools.Interpreter.IronPythonInterpreter.CreateDomain(RemoteInterpreterProxy& remoteInterpreter) at Microsoft.IronPythonTools.Interpreter.IronPythonInterpreter.InitializeRemoteDomain() at Microsoft.IronPythonTools.Interpreter.IronPythonInterpreter..ctor(IronPythonInterpreterFactory factory, PythonTypeDatabase typeDb) at Microsoft.IronPythonTools.Interpreter.IronPythonInterpreterFactory.CreateInterpreter() at Microsoft.PythonTools.Repl.PythonReplEvaluator.get_ReplAnalyzer() at Microsoft.PythonTools.Extensions.GetAnalyzer(ITextView textView) at Microsoft.PythonTools.Intellisense.IntellisenseControllerProvider.TryCreateIntellisenseController(ITextView textView, IList1 subjectBuffers) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.IntellisenseManagerConnectionListener.<>c_DisplayClass5.b_1(IIntellisenseControllerProvider provider) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension,TMetadata,TExtensionInstance](Object errorSource, Lazy2 provider, Func2 getter)`

The generated code is as following (this project still is not displayed in the Solution)

project1.py :

```
print("hello world")
```

Changed the above to `print "Hello world"` since I'm using Python 2.7 but it didn't fix the problem

project1.pyproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>690e6ad3-edb2-42cc-8db1-85cdf487d241</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectHome>.</ProjectHome>
    <StartupFile>WebScraper.py</StartupFile>
    <SearchPath>
    </SearchPath>
    <WorkingDirectory>.</WorkingDirectory>
    <InterpreterId>80659ab7-4d53-4e0c-8588-a766116cbd46</InterpreterId>
    <LaunchProvider>IronPython (.NET) launcher</LaunchProvider>
    <InterpreterVersion>2.7</InterpreterVersion>
    <OutputPath>.</OutputPath>
    <Name>WebScraper</Name>
    <RootNamespace>WebScraper</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="WebScraper.py" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: What is the "InnerException" of your exception?

Comment: This is all i see, it pops up in an alert dialogue.. I don't know how to get more information from it

Comment: You need to look at the details of the exception when you get the dialog.  You can then check the InnerException to see what the "real" exception is.  Make sure you're running in Debug and not Release, as well.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I'm not sure how that's done but I think I found the information in the ActivityLog.xml and it's details

Comment: Can you show the python code you're calling?

Comment: @ReedCopsey I posted the generated code and the proj file in the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution at the end came down to uninstalling all IronPython's (2.6 and 2.7) and then uninstalling the Python Tools for Visual Studio. Then reinstalling IronPython 2.7 and not installing any of the "Tools" when selecting components (I think this is an important part since they clash with each other as I understand it) Then reinstalling the Python Tools version 1.5 (I use VS 2012)

Comment: I've done this numerous times this weekend, but today I un-checked 'Silverlight Tools' when installing Iron Python 2.7.3.  Your solution fixed my problem, but I'm going to try to re-produce the problem to indeed pin down why this is the case.

Comment: I did not need to uninstall PTVS, but instead uninstalled IronPython (2.7.5) and re-installed with un-checking 'Silverlight Tools'. Everything seems to work so far with no more issues.