# Python.CreateEngine() eventually throws System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, ironpython

After several cycles of debugging,  Python.CreateEngine() eventually throws the exception shown below. I don't know why this is occurring and the version that I have installed is actually 2.7.4.1.  I end up reinstalling IronPython and the exception disappears, but it eventually returns.  I am using VS2010 with Windows 7.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Failed to load language 'IronPython 2.7.2.1': Method not found: '!!1[] Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ArrayUtils.ConvertAll(!!0[], System.Func`2<!!0,!!1>)'.
  Source=Microsoft.Scripting
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LanguageConfiguration.LoadLanguageContext(ScriptDomainManager domainManager, Boolean& alreadyLoaded)
       at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DlrConfiguration.LoadLanguageContext(ScriptDomainManager manager, LanguageConfiguration config)
       at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DlrConfiguration.TryLoadLanguage(ScriptDomainManager manager, AssemblyQualifiedTypeName providerName, LanguageContext& language)
       at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.ScriptDomainManager.GetLanguageByTypeName(String providerAssemblyQualifiedTypeName)
       at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptRuntime.GetEngineByTypeName(String assemblyQualifiedTypeName)
       at IronPython.Hosting.Python.GetEngine(ScriptRuntime runtime)
       at IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine()
       at OneWireTest.Form1.InitializeScriptEngine() in D:\IPYTest\Form1.cs:line 374
  InnerException: System.MissingMethodException
       HResult=-2146233069
       Message=Method not found: '!!1[] Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ArrayUtils.ConvertAll(!!0[], System.Func`2<!!0,!!1>)'.
       Source=IronPython
       StackTrace:
            at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext..ctor(ScriptDomainManager manager, IDictionary`2 options)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft.Scripting.dll` and `Microsoft.Dynamic.dll` that came with the IronPython release? Are you using an installed release or NuGet packages? Versions?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Scripting.dll from the install release.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12680535/468244). Could there be multiple IronPython versions around? Or at least Dynamic/Scripting.dlls? I guess IronRuby could also be an issue..